# Is there a way to copy content from a broken (no display) m1 macbook to another m1 macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, copy-paste

The broken MacBook is an M1, still turns on, but the display is broken so no visual. There are no external monitors to connect either. I don't wanna do any open-heart surgery on the broken MacBook either, such as removing the disk etc.

I found that we can connect the two MacBooks using USB-C or Thunderbolt cable, then use the Target Disk Mode. Unfortunately, to do this, the broken MacBook needs to have a display which I don't have.

What other pragmatic approaches do I have to get the content copied to the new MacBook?

Comment: There's no disk on the M1 MacBook to remove.  The correct answer is to plug an external monitor into the MacBook.

Comment: You can't 'remove the disk' -- the SSD modules are soldered onto the logic board, and the disk controller is in the M1 CPU. Can you explain how the MacBook came to lose its display? I suppose there's no point in asking you if you have a backup?

Comment: What do you  mean with "There are no external monitors to connect either"? Did you connect one and it didn't worked, or do you not have access to an external monitor?

Comment: I don't have an external monitor to extend the display.

Comment: I dropped the MacBook and it's display has a crack and cannot see anything, just black with those multi-colored lines that appear :(

Answer (score 1):

The most pragmatic approach here is to connect an external display. That will let you login as normal on your M1 laptop, and from there you can copy over files to network storage, USB storage or similar.

A tool such as [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) can help you easily create a full copy of everything.